# flutter IOS: got throwToolExit error when running on simulator

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

I am trying run my application on IOS simulator, After pod install and run application I got this error:

```
[+2469 ms] Could not build the application for the simulator.
[   +2 ms] Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro.
[   +3 ms] "flutter run" took 32,047ms.
[   +4 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:669:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1125:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:288:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:236:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:92:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           
           
[ +255 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 253ms
[   +1 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 1
```

What is the problem ? and how could I found what is the problem?

This is my doctor:

```
alt@alts-MacBook-Pro ~ % flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on macOS 12.0.1 21A559 darwin-x64, locale
    en)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.62.0)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
alt@alts-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

Comment: i am facing the same issue, can you share solution how you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Do a `flutter clean` first.

If it doesn't work

```
rm ios/Podfile
pub upgrade
pub get
cd ios && pod update
flutter clean && flutter run
```

Comment: Let me do it and I will announce you.

Comment: I got same error @flakerimi

Comment: can you create new blank project and try to run it on simulator

Comment: As @flakerimi comments, only when I run `flutter create .` in my existing project, first removing all the flutter generated folders and files - then it works.  Existing pubspec.yaml can stay, did not get overwritten when I ran the command

Answer (score 0):

I were getting above error. I have added `--no-sound-null-safety` as run argument and it worked like charm.

Run the flutter with given command:

`flutter run --no-sound-null-safety`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, I run an VPN and my promlem was solved.